# Нужны ли в этом предложении запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Вот Ваш комментарий действительно противно читать!

Answer (score 5):

> Нужны ли в этом предложении запятые?

**Не нужны.**

См. ***Остроумова О., Фрамполь О.  "Трудности русской пунктуации. Словарь вводных слов, сочетаний и предложений":***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То же и в [***"Словаре-справочнике по пунктуации"  Пахомова В.М. и др.***](http://punktuaciya.academic.ru/157)

===

В приведённом Вами предложении есть ещё одно спорное слово   — ***действительно***. Про его возможное обособление справочник Пахомова говорит: [***"В спорных случаях вопрос о расстановке знаков препинания решает автор текста".***](http://punktuaciya.academic.ru/201)

Я бы это слово в рассматриваемом предложении не обособлял: ***действительно*** в сочетании с частицей ***вот*** здесь более походит не на вводное слово, а  на усилительную частицу.

Из словаря ***Фрамполь:***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, вставьте выдержки в ваш ответ текстом, а не изображением.

Answer (score 1):

"Вот Ваш комментарий действительно противно читать!". Слово "действительно"не обособляется (в данном случае это наречие), частица ВОТ с указательным значением (вот ваш комментарий) также не обособляется.

ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬНО. I. нареч. В действительности, подлинно, в самом деле. Он д. очень устал. II. вводн. сл. Подтверждает чью-л. мысль, выражает уверенность в чём-л. На этот раз, д., он прав. III. частица. Употр. для выражения утверждения; да, верно. Он так сказал? - Д.

Хотя часто говорится о том, что установить синтаксическую роль слова "действительно" сложно, в справочнике  "Трудные случаи пунктуации" есть хорошая подсказка: вводным словом мы подтверждаем **сказанное ранее**, обычно с этого слова начинается доказательство истинности **уже приведенного суждения.**

В приведенном примере  сказанное ранее не доказывается, оппоненты просто обмениваются репликами.